# How can i integrate a project angular4 to another project angular4

Tags: angular, architecture, frameworks, integration

I want to use the [ngx-dynamic-dashboard framework](https://github.com/catalogicsoftware/ngx-dynamic-dashboard-framework#ngx-dynamic-dashboard-framework) in my existing project in angular4.

My question is the following :
Can I create a folder which contains this framework and change `app.module` with `dashboard.module` and include it to my `app.module`.

Is it a good practice?

I need some advice from people which have an experience with angular 4.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to merge two Angular4 projects to one?

Yes, you can do this.

But for this merging, you need to do everything manually and you have to think for the nesting and integration of various modules and to the main module e.g. NgModule.

An NgModule describes how the application parts fit together. Every application has at least one Angular module, the root module that you bootstrap to launch the application. By convention, it is usually called AppModule.